# How use Log4j methods in log4j2

Tags: maven, migration, log4j, log4j2, compatibility

I am trying to upgrade log4j to log4j2.I am using some methods of log4j1 like removeAllappender(),setName(), these not found in log4j2.

I have included these dependencies:-

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried to include bridge also but it fails the build. How can I solve these?
note:-My project is in maven.

**i have also added bridge dependency 1.x to 2.x

Comment: You are doing logger configuration in code?

Comment: I am using it for printing logs